# Choose optimal smoothing parameter for smooth spline

Tags: r, lambda, smoothing, spline

How can we choose the optimal value of `lambda` (smoothing parameter
) in the `smooth.spline()` function? What range of values that `lambda` could take? (I have read somewhere that lambda could take values from 0 to 1.5 but I'm not quite sure, any suggestions?)

Use the dataset `data1` as the calibration data and `data2` as the validation data.

To download the data type the following commands, noting that "username" and "password" needs to be replaced by your logging information from the Human Mortality Database. You can go to website https://mortality.org/ and create the account (will take less than 30s).

```
library(demography)
JPNmort <- hmd.mx(country = "JPN", username = "username", password = "password")
library(demography)
library(splines)

#Read Japan mortality data from the Human Mortality Database
JPNmort <- hmd.mx("JPN","username","password")

age = 2:110

data1= cbind(1:109, 
                 JPNmort[["rate"]][["total"]][age, "2016"], 
                 JPNmort[["pop"]][["total"]][age, "2016"])
data2 = cbind(1:109, 
                   JPNmort[["rate"]][["total"]][age, "2017"],
                   JPNmort[["pop"]][["total"]][age, "2017"])

#Reformat data rows and columns
column.names = c("Age", "mu_x", "Ec_x")
rownames(data1) = NULL
rownames(data2) = NULL

colnames(data1) = column.names
colnames(data2) = column.names
```

I created the codes below to find the optimal lambda, wondering if it is eligible?

```
splineres <- function(lambda){
  
    
    sm.spline <- smooth.spline(x=data1[, "Age"], y=data1[, "mu_x"], lambda = lambda)
    res <- fitted(sm.spline) - data2[, "mu_x"]
    
  return(sum(res^2))
}

lambda <- seq(0, 1.5, by = 0.001)
ss <- rep(0, length(lambda))

for (i in 1:length(lambda)){
  ss[i] <- splineres(lambda[i])
}

lambda[which.min(ss)]
```